# Isometric embedding of spherical 3-manifolds in Euclidean spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

I have an interesting problem in materials science that I think can be solved by obtaining a mapping, which is one-to-one, continuous and preserves the metric, from spherical 3-manifods (defined as $S^3/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a finite subgroup of $SO(4)$) to Euclidean space of some dimension $n$ $\left( \mathbb{R}^n \right)$. I believe this mapping is an isometric embedding.

I am primarily interested in obtaining a mapping to any $\mathbb{R}^n$ (not necessarily the smallest $n$ but something reasonable). For example, the group of proper rotations, $SO(3)$, I think, is a spherical 3-manifold ($S^3/(-I_{4\times4}$)), where $I_{4\times4}$ is the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix. This manifold can be isometrically embedded in $\mathbb{R}^9$ through the $3 \times 3$ matrix representation of that rotation. I am wondering if such embeddings are known for other spherical 3-manifolds. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit 1: I want to make this a little more specific if it helps. I am interested in the isometric embedding of $S^3/2O$, where $2O$ is the binary ocatahedral point group (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_octahedral_group). Alternatively, this space is equivalent to the quotient space $SO(3)/O$, where $O$ is the octahedral point group $(2,3,4)$.

Comment: If you just want existence, I think you may want to look at the second [Nash embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem). It's much, much more powerful than what you're looking for. Another point to consider is that all spherical manifolds are quotients of the isometry group $SO(4)$, so that may be exploitable for this particular problem.

Comment: @Neal - More than just the existence, I am interested in the mapping. The embedding of SO(3) is an example where I know the mapping from quaternions to a 3×3×3 matrix. I don't know much about the properties of quotient spaces of SO(4)SO(4). Could you provide me with any resources that I could read. Thanks!

Comment: See for example: https://ldtopology.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/symmetric-decompositions-of-the-4-sphere/ .  Relatively few spherical 3-manifolds embed in R^4.  The list is due to Jon Hillman, and appears here: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0810.2346

Comment: See the discussion at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31222/c1-isometric-embedding-of-flat-torus-into-mathbbr3 concerning "constructive" versions of Nash isometric embedding.

Comment: +1. This is a GREAT question. If there's no answers I might put a bounty. I looked at your profile and saw you followed a proposal for a Materials Modeling Stack Exchange. If you don't mind another attempt at a Materials proposal, would you be so kind to commit to this? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=ZTUyZWY5OTQ1NDI4ZGVlMmU5MzM0ZThiZjNhOTRkYWFlMTA1NjM0OWEzOTZhYzlmMTBlNWQ4ZmIzYWE3MWFkN-4At28O9gekwyERVbYPhFIPwyHiajfB5BeMyrZKJaYV0  It started slow but lately it's been booming with 5 commitments/day and very soon it will reach 200.